# Can't connect my RPi to internet via ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet

The same cable when connected with my Mac works perfectly but when connected to my Raspberry Pi 3 model b i can't connect to internet. This is the new output of the ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:97:57:e6  
          inet addr:169.254.179.161  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe97:57e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26577 (25.9 KiB)  TX bytes:26146 (25.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:73608 (71.8 KiB)  TX bytes:73608 (71.8 KiB)
```

I changed interfaces file and now looks like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

[image: And this is view from my Mac]

Comment: What is the cable connected to? Is it a router or the Mac? Whatever it is it is not allocating an address using DHCP. Do not fiddle with the interfaces file, it should work out of the box; see  [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 2):

Your interface configuration file (`/etc/network/interfaces/`) tells me that your Ethernet interface `eth0` is set to `manual` rather than to communicate with a DHCP server to obtain an IP address, which is what you want your Pi to do. Your `interfaces` file looked like this:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual 
...
```

Remove the line `iface eth0 inet manual` and add at least these two lines to your `interfaces` configuration file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**auto eth0**: This line will attempt to bring your Ethernet interface up when your Raspberry Pi boots.

**iface eth0 inet dhcp**: This line instructs your Raspberry Pi to attempt to obtain a DHCP lease for your Ethernet interface. You previously had your Ethernet interface set to `manual`, which is used for bridged connections.

You may also consider adding this line to your `interfaces` file:

**allow-hotplug eth0**: This line attempts to bring up your Ethernet interface when a hotplug event (*i.e.* an Ethernet cable is plugged in) occurs.

A detailed description of many, if not all, parameters that may be entered in your `interfaces` file can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax).

Comment: auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface vlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1

Comment: Yeah, there's the problem. `inet manual` is used for bridged connections, which is not what you want (read more [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645000/what-is-the-difference-between-iface-eth0-inet-manual-and-iface-eth0-inet-static)). Try changing `manual` to `dhcp` and then restart networking with `sudo service networking restart`.

Comment: You may also want to add the lines `auto eth0`, which starts that interface at boot, and `allow-hotplug eth0` to your `interaces` file. As explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax) `auto` brings up this interface at boot, and `allow-hotplug` brings up the interface when a cable is plugged in or some other "hot plug" event.

Comment: Comments should not be used for extended discussions.  Please could you  add the additional information as an edit to your question.

Comment: `iface eth0 inet manual` is the **STANDARD** correct setting. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 0):

If time, date is not correctly set, the DNS resolving is not working.
To setup time, date and timezone do:

---

Check time, date and timezone

```
timedatectl status
```

---

Chose you're timezone:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

---

Disable ntp

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp false
```

---

Set correct timezone, example: Buenos Aires

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
```

---

Set correct date and time

```
sudo timedatectl set-time "2020-08-27 13:08:27"
```

---

Enable ntp

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

---

Recheck time, date and timezone

```
timedatectl status
```

or

```
timedatectl show
```

---

---EDIT---

The Raspberry Pi has no battery, so time and date get reseted as soon as the rbp remains without power.